# C# SQLDataAdapter - Issues with INSERT

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows

Please refer to the question that started it all for me: [C# SQLDataAdapter - Not inserting data into DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32385295/c-sharp-sqldataadapter-not-inserting-data-into-db/32385507#32385507)

I'm developing an archival system, well building on to it I should say. But my latest issue looks like this once I hit `var rowsAffected = sqlAdapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();`:

`Additional information: The parameterized query '(@TableID int,@RowID int,@RowState tinyint,@UserID int,@XMLHisto' expects the parameter '@TableID', which was not supplied.`

Now here's where it potentially gets a little tricky.. the tables that I'm trying to INSERT into, they don't have any primary or foreign keys associated to them. Not my design. I'm wondering if the above execute() call is having troubles with the INSERT because of this. I dont' have anything that I need to set as @@Identity because.. well I don't have anything like that available.

Thoughts?

**Update**:

As requested here's the query and the sql cmd..

```
string strInsertSQL = "INSERT INTO <tableName> (TableID, RowID, ModifyDate, RowState, UserID, XMLHistory, RowDescription) " +
                            "VALUES (@TableID, @RowID, GetDate(), @RowState, @UserID, @XMLHistory, @RowDescription); SET @NewID = @@Identity"; // SET statement needed? 

sqlComm = new SqlCommand(strInsertSQL, sqlConnArchive);
sqlComm.Parameters.Add("@TableID", SqlDbType.Int, 4, "TableID"); // Not sure if this is needed since primary key doesn't exist? 
// More params added here
```

**Update:**

On a whim I wanted to check to see what the InsertCommand.Parameters held. I took a look at @TableID value and it was Null.

```
sqlAdapter.Fill(myDS.myTable); // myTable.count = 7k+
var x = sqlAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters; // x-@tableID value = null
var rowsAffected = sqlAdapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I have a feeling that's why I'm seeing this error. Anyone have any thoughts on how I can resolve this?

Comment: You haven't included the SQL for InsertCommand. How can we see what is wrong?

Comment: @GlenThomas - added above.

Comment: Can you get us schema for that table?

Comment: sorry unfortunately no on the schema. But please do check the update I just included up top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see where you're actually setting the value of the parameter(s). You add the parameter, but your code doesn't show that you ever populate the parameter with a value.

```
sqlComm = new SqlCommand(strInsertSQL, sqlConnArchive);
var tableIdParam = new SqlParameter("@TableId", SqlDbType.Int, 4);
tableIdParam.Value = 99; //whatever id value you want to set here
sqlComm.Parameters.Add(tableIdParam);
```

If, on the other hand, the TableId column has an identity specifcation, then modify your sql string and leave TableId out of it altogether - the database will provide it on insert.

Comment: Hm. Well I'm getting data back and I can confirm that it is populating the dataset.datatable of the intended target. It's just the issue is that the insert back to the DB is still not working.

Comment: OK. Can you include a more complete sample? All of the code that deals with the INSERT would be ideal, from where you declare the SQL string to the point you call ExecuteNonQuery().

Comment: Your comment got me thinking, so I created a function for the general save and set the values of the params. `sqlAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters[0].Value = tableID;` "tableID being a param that I pass back.  etc etc.. thanks, this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

The error is because it is null. Make the TableID column as Identity in the table.

Comment: I'm not up on my datasets, but can you do that if your table doesn't have a primary key?

Comment: yes. we can do that. Primary key has nothing to do with Identity column.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course you are not supplying the value..

In your method

```
sqlComm.Parameters.Add("@TableID", SqlDbType.Int, 4, "TableID")
// the value '4' here specifies the size of the column not value.
// for example max length of a string if you are about to supply a varchar
```

.

You can supply a value by two methods

**Either**

```
sqlComm.Parameters.Add("@TableID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 4;
```

**Or**

```
sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TableID", 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating data adapter but the way you use the data adapter is like using a SqlCommand.

Refer this for way to use data adapter: [Using Data Adapter](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0560__ADO.Net/Insertcommandwithparameters.htm)

To use a sql command,

```
string strInsertSQL = "INSERT INTO <tableName> (TableID, RowID, ModifyDate, RowState, UserID, XMLHistory, RowDescription) " +
                            "VALUES (@TableID, @RowID, GetDate(), @RowState, @UserID, @XMLHistory, @RowDescription)"

sqlComm = new SqlCommand(strInsertSQL, sqlConnArchive);
sqlComm.Parameters.Add("@TableID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1; //Set it to the value you want to insert
..... the rest of the parameters

sqlConnArchive.Open();
sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```